# Certora storage hook for a nested mapping

Tags: certora

In [Certora's](https://www.certora.com/) CVL, I can track storage writes of a mapping. If my solidity looks like this:

```js
mapping(address => bool) internal _hasVoted;
```

I can do the following to "listen" for storage writes on the mapping:

```js
hook Sstore _hasVoted[KEY address voter] bool newVal (bool oldVal) STORAGE {
    // some stuff here...
```

How would I do this for a nested mapping?

```js
mapping(address => mapping(address => bool)) internal _hasVoted;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
hook Sstore _hasVoted[KEY address vault][KEY address voter] bool newVal (bool oldVal) STORAGE {
    // stuff...
}
```